# $\sum (f(\frac{k}{n})) + \sum (f^{-1}(\frac{k}{n}))$

Tags: inequality, inverse

I would appreciate some help with the following Putnam preparatory problem (you can google Putnam 2010, Week 3, inequalities, problem 13):

Let $f$ be a continuous and monotonically increasing function such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. Prove that:
$f(0.1)+f(0.2)+···+f(0.9)+f^{−1}(0.1)+f^{−1}(0.2)+···+f^{−1}(0.9) ≤ 9.9$ (here $f^{−1}$ is the inverse function of $f$).

I've made two attempts and came up with either a more relaxed bound (10.0) or a tighter bound (9.5) but for a special case (when $f(x)$ doesn't change convexity). I can present those if anyone interested (I used $\int_a^b f(x)dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{−1}(x)dx=bf(b)−af(a)$ and lower Darboux sums or trapezoidal method), but bottom line is I couldn't prove the general 9.9 bound.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not look like any of the Putnam 2010 problems... Do you mean Putnam 2010, or perhaps some worksheet title the year 2010 related to Putnam?

Comment: It's part of a Putnam _preparatory_ set. [link](https://www.coursehero.com/file/9903622/INEQUALITIES-Part-2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I present and idea on how you could start: We start the same way as you probably already did, but then take care of a detail.

The core idea is following:

What we're trying to do here is making use of the fact that the red square is always ignored in the summation: (The yellow rectangles represent the sums.)

[image]

---

Surely $$\int_0^1 f(x) dx + \int_0^1 f^{-1}(x) dx = 1 \qquad (1)$$

Let $x_k = 0.1\cdot k$. Then define the piecewise constant step function $g(x) = f(x_k)$ for $ x \in [x_k,x_{k+1})$ and similarly $g^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(x_k)$ for $x \in [x_k, x_{k+1})$. (Note that I just use the symbol $g^{-1}$ for symmetry reasons, but $g^{-1}$ does *not* denote the inverse of $g$.)Then surely $g(x) \leq f(x)$ and $g^{-1}(x) \leq f(x) \forall x \in [0,1]$.

Therefore

$$\frac{1}{10}(f(0.1)+f(0.2)+\ldots+f(0.9))=\int_{0.1}^1 g(x) dx \leq \int_{0.1}^1 f(x)dx \qquad (2)$$
and

$$\frac{1}{10}(f^{-1}(0.1)+f^{-1}(0.2)+\ldots+f^{-1}(0.9))=\int_{0.1}^1 g^{-1}(x) dx \leq \int_{0.1}^1 f^{-1}(x)dx \qquad (3)$$

Now note that $$G:=\int_0^{0.1} g(x) dx + \int_0^{0.1} g^{-1}(x)dx = 0 \qquad (4)$$

Now we just have to consider $$F:=\int_0^{0.1} f(x) dx + \int_0^{0.1} f^{-1}(x)dx \qquad (5)$$

So now we can add $(2)$ and $(3)$ and multiply by $10$ and get

$$\sum_{k=1}^9 f(x_k) + f^{-1}(x_k)  \overset{(2) \& (3)}{\leq} 10\int_{0.1}^1 f(x) dx + 10\int_{0.1}^1 f^{-1}(x) dx \overset{(1)\& (5)}{=} 10(1-F) $$

It remains to show that $F \geq 0.01$:

Let $a=0$ and $b=0.1$.

Then $$\begin{align*}F  &=  \int_0^b f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{b} f^{−1}(x)dx  \\ 
 & \geq \int_0^b \min\{f(x),b\} dx+\int_{0}^{b} \min\{f^{−1}(x),b\}dx \\
& =b^2 = 0.01
\end{align*}$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Nice answer +1.

Comment: Thank you, flawr! I was missing the F part in my proof and that makes all the difference.

Comment: You're welcome, it was a nice problem to figure out!

Comment: flawr, I think there is a flaw (excuse the pun ;-)) in the proof: namely, the assumption $f(b) \leq b$ is contrary to $b f(b) \geq b^2$, isn't it?

Comment: Oh no, you're right! Well it is certainly clear from the image that $F \geq 0.01$, but obviously the last inequality does not work. I just thought it would be a nice touch to incorporate this inequality :) I adjusted the proof now.

Comment: I don't quite get it: since both $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ are increasing on $[0,1]$, with $f(1)=1$, then $min\{f(x),1\} = f(x)$ and $min\{f^{-1}(x),1\} = f^{-1}(x)$. And how did you get $\int_0^b (min\{f(x),1\}+min\{f^{-1}(x),1\})dx = b^2$? Perhaps you meant $min \{f(x),x\}$? Even so, if $min \{f(x),x\}=x$ that cannot also hold for $min \{f^{-1}(x),x\}$. What am I missing? Thx.

Comment: That should have been a $b = 0.1$ instead of a $1$, sorry! The idea is that we can bound $F$ from below by the area of the red square.

Comment: Actually, the geometric proof is probably best. $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ are symmetric with respect to line y=x. Assume first that $f(b) < b=0.1$. Let points $P_1(b,b)$, $P_2(b,f(b))$, $P_3(f^{-1}(b),b)$. $\int_0^b f(x) dx = A_1$ = area under f(x) between X axis and $P_2$. $\int_0^b f^{-1}(x) dx =$  area of square with edge b (=$A_0$) - area between Y axis and $P_3$ (=$A_2$)  + area under $ f^{-1}(x)$ above line $y=b$, $P_3$ and $P_1$(=$A_3$). But $A_1=A_2$, due to symmetry. Hence sum of integrals is greater than $A_0=b^2$. The case $f(b)>b$ implies $f^{-1}(b)<b$ and is treated similarly.